# ggplot2 bar chart with two bars for each x value of data and two y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I struggle to create a bar chart with two different y-axis and two bars for each x -value (category).
I have different types of categories of data (see below) for each I have two values that I want to plot side by side (`price` and `number`). However, the values for each category are far apart, which makes the bars of the `number` category become almost invisible. Thus, I want to add a second y-axis (one for the `price` one for the `number`) to allow a comparison between the two categories.

Example data:

```
 Cat Type        Value
1 A  price        12745
2 A  number           5
3 B  price     34874368
4 B  number         143
5 C  price        84526
6 C  number          11
```

I use the following R code (ggplot2) to create the plot:

```
plot = ggplot(df ,aes(x=Cat, fill=Type, y=Value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  theme_bw() +
  labs_pubr() +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
plot
```

`scale_y_continuous` and `sec.axis` but I did not manage to assign the y-axis to the type of data.

```
  scale_y_continuous(
    "price", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "number")
  ) +
```

I am happy for every hint :)

Comment: In ggplot2 you can't assign a series to an "axis" as e.g. in Excel. Instead you have to transform your data. As a starting point see e.g. `https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

```
df=tribble(
~Id, ~Cat, ~Type, ~Value,
1, "A", "price", 13,
2, "A", "number", 5,
3, "B", "price", 19,
4, "B", "number", 12,
5, "C", "price", 8,
6, "C", "number", 11)

df %>% ggplot(aes(Cat))


df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Type, fill=Type, y=Value))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_grid(~Cat)
```

[image]

P.S.
I changed your values a bit because you could not see much when the differences were of the order of 10 ^ 7!

With these numbers, the logarithmic scale is better suited

```
df=tribble(
  ~Id, ~Cat, ~Type, ~Value,
  1, "A", "price", 12745,
  2, "A", "number", 5,
  3, "B", "price", 34874368,
  4, "B", "number", 143,
  5, "C", "price", 84526,
  6, "C", "number", 11)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Type, fill=Type, y=Value))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')+
  facet_grid(~Cat)
```

[image]

Comment: ```P.S. I changed your values a bit because you could not see much when the differences were of the order of 10 ^ 7!```` ---

That is my problem! The numbers are far apart. That is why I need a second y-axis

Comment: The different Y axes don't get the job done. Better use a logarithmic scale. Take a look at my modified answer.

Comment: If I helped, please mark the solution you approved!

Answer (score 0):

The idea as I understand is to split the graphs by Type, and you can do this using the helpful `ggplot` `facet_wrap() verb`. Then use the `scales` package to fix the rounding along the y-axis.

[image]

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble(Cat = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),  Type = c("price", "number", "price", "number","price", "number")
              , Value = c(12745, 5, 34874368, 143, 84526, 11))

tbl %>%
  ggplot(aes(Cat, Value, fill = Cat)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~Type, scales = "free") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format())
```

Comment: I thought about splitting but I have way more than 3 categories and would like to have teh bars side by side.

Comment: You can use coord_flip() if you have many categories